# No WiFi nor Ethernet connection on Dell Inspiron/ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: wireless, ethernet, broadcom, wired

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron. After updating I found myself with no WiFi adapter installed. I tried to restore the WiFi adapter by running [this script](https://github.com/ricfix/linux_scripts/blob/1dfbb8d7d4f959e063a97d04ccfa55a2243b04f3/fix_wifi_dell5401/fix_wifi.sh) I found on GitHub.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "
Powered by:
  ___  _      ___  _      
 | _ \(_) __ | __|(_)__ __
 |   /| |/ _|| _| | |\ \ /
 |_|_\|_|\__||_|  |_|/_\_\
"
echo""
sudo cd /tmp/
sudo wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1/linux-headers-5.1.0-050100_5.1.0-050100.201905052130_all.deb
sudo wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1/linux-headers-5.1.0-050100-generic_5.1.0-050100.201905052130_amd64.deb
sudo wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1/linux-image-unsigned-5.1.0-050100-generic_5.1.0-050100.201905052130_amd64.deb
sudo wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1/linux-modules-5.1.0-050100-generic_5.1.0-050100.201905052130_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

#Wifi drive install
sudo wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz
sudo tar -xzvf iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz
sudo cp iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode /lib/firmware/
echo "Please Reboot your pc"
~
```

After rebooting (as prompted to do once the script was executed), the wired connection sign disappeared from the taskbar as well. I opened the system settings/network connections and got this:

[image]

It seems I do have a connection 
but still no working internet connection!!!

Output of the Wireless Script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 10 Nov 2019 13:57 EET +0200

Booted last: 10 Nov 2019 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.1.0-050100-generic #201905052130 SMP Mon May 6 01:32:59 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Unity

##### lspci #############################

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:0655]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:670b Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:0084 Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 03f0:e111 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

dell_laptop            20480  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,dell_laptop
dell_wmi               20480  0
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi_bmof               16384  0
bcma                   61440  0
wmi                    32768  6 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  45056  4 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp7s0
       valid_lft 84452sec preferred_lft 84452sec
    inet6 2a02:2149:8419:a900:48c4:2602:bb11:a9e2/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86354sec preferred_lft 43154sec
    inet6 2a02:2149:8419:a900:929a:f7a2:5cd3:f74f/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86354sec preferred_lft 43154sec
    inet6 fe80::b2aa:4781:308f:8281/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp7s0 proto static metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    None found.

Running:

root      1159     1  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 /snap/network-manager/379/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --config-dir=/var/snap/network-manager/379/conf.d/ --config=/snap/network-manager/379/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf --log-level=INFO --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager is not installed (package "network-manager").

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: No such file or directory

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Athens (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp7s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp7s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.1.0-050100-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     9FF0F781F456EC613F149E3
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           bcma
vermagic:       5.1.0-050100-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.network-manager.rules]
# network-manager
KERNEL=="rfkill", TAG+="snap_network-manager_networkmanager"
# ppp
KERNEL=="ppp", TAG+="snap_network-manager_networkmanager"
# ppp
KERNEL=="tty[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*", TAG+="snap_network-manager_networkmanager"
TAG=="snap_network-manager_networkmanager", RUN+="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper $env{ACTION} snap_network-manager_networkmanager $devpath $major:$minor"

##### dmesg #############################

[   63.488988] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: Link is Down
[   65.245800] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   65.245810] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp7s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Let's start by actually identifying the hardware. Please go through [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/816190) and once completed, paste the link of the paste in question. Moreover, please don't run any script from internet blindly. It seems the script installed kernel v5.1 which IMO is an overkill.

Comment: hi, https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Gwb6ygx5zj/

Comment: I'm not sure about the limitations of NetworkManager snap package. Please remove network-manager using `snap remove network-manager` and install deb package using apt. For that run `sudo apt install network-manager`. Also, let me know if [it](https://askubuntu.com/q/55868/816190) helps.

Comment: The answer is obvious. `bcmwl-kernel-source` should be installed, but the one supplied with Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't build on an unsupported mainline kernel.

Comment: @Kulfy Network Manager has no relation to that at all.

Comment: @Pilot6 I understand but `NetworkManager state` in the output mentions `cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: No such file or directory`. As I said earlier I'm not sure about the limitations of that snap package. I think author of the script need to modify it to check status of NetworkManager even if that's a snap package.

Comment: @kulfy i installed the latest stable kernel (5.3.10) and fixed the ethernet connection issue! tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with the same problem. 
Try this:

1. disable Secure Boot in UEFI (BIOS) settings
2. reinstall linux firmware `sudo apt install linux-firmware`
3. add in grub the parameter pcie_aspm=off :

   `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

   Add `pcie_aspm=off` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
4. reboot

It worked for me, 
Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

1- Go to Software & Updates, and then go to additional drivers tab. Within that tab select the driver for the WiFi adapter. Finally, apply changes.

2- After sound that you need to update the drivers. You can go through updates via GUI but the best way is using the command line:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt  --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

3- Finally, you have to disable the secure boot from your BIOS. The way to do that depends on your laptop/pc. Usually F2 or F3 let you access the BIOS setup and there you have to search for the secure boot option and disable it.

4- Reboot and (hopefully) enjoy.

Comment: As of now there's no evidence that OP has Broadcom Wifi.

Comment: True, but Dell Inspiron series uses Broadcom Wifi Adapter

Comment: This ain't true. I personally use Dell Inspiron 5559 and that has Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160.

Comment: @Kulfy i removed network-manager using snap then installed the .deb package and when opening network manager i get this error message: ''the system network services are not compatible with this version '' should i change kernel v5.1 ? if so, which one should i install and how?? tnx.

Comment: @StamatisDiamantopoulos Go to Advance options for Ubuntu when GRUB menu appear and choose a previous kernel like 5.0 or 4.15 if there.

Comment: @esteban vergara. i followed the instructions described in your answer but it did not work. still no wifi ...